# IBM Worklight server failing to start project

Tags: java, window, ibm-mobilefirst

```
Windows 7; Java 1.7; Worklight 7.0:
```

Just started getting this error; has anyone else run into this?
`

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0320E: Failed to check whether the admin services are ready. Caused by: [project rta]
Connection refused: connect
[ERROR   ] FWLST0003E: ========= Failed starting project /rta [project rta]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[ERROR   ] null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[ERROR   ] FWLSE4011E: StatusMessage [severity=ERROR, message='null', timestamp=1462897073437, detailedMessage=java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator$1.run(JeeProjectActivator.java:239)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:798)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout while waiting for the management service to start up.120 secs.
    at com.worklight.core.init.WorklightServletInitializer$1.run(WorklightServletInitializer.java:150)
    at com.worklight.core.init.WorklightServletInitializer.initialize(WorklightServletInitializer.java:193)
    ... 6 more
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IBM Java, try instead to install Oracle Java and see if this has gone away.

You can also try removing the MobileFirst Development Server (the folder that appears in your Solution view in Eclipse. Then simply restart Eclipse, this should recreate a fresh copy of the server and the error may be gone then.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, should I actually have the contents deleted?

Comment: Just click delete... as shown in the image I've added.